# Resizable containment doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, resizable

I've made a div draggable and resizable. The containment on draggable seems to work but it doesn't on resizable. Do you know why ? Here is my HTML :

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="area"></div>
</div>
```

And my jquery code is (where self.$area is the jquery object representing the .area div) :

```
    self.$area.resizable({
        containment : 'parent',
    });

    self.$area.draggable({
        containment : '.page',
    });
```

My .area is on an absolute position and my .page is relative.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this **[demo JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/zN62s/)** for a simple `draggable + resizable` with `containment`

code:

```
<div id="container" class="ui-widget-content">
<h3 class="ui-widget-header">Containment</h3>
<div id="resizable" class="ui-state-active">
<h3 class="ui-widget-header">Draggable & Resizable</h3>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
     $( "#resizable" ).draggable({containment: "#container"}).resizable({
containment: "#container"
});
</script>
```

});

Comment: It's what I've did. But it doesn't work for me (jQuery UI - v1.11.0).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. In my div I had an  like that :

```
<div class="page">
    <img src="..." alt="" class="imgPage" />
    <div class="area"></div>
</div>
```

The dimensions for the image are 100%*100%. So I've put this image for the containment and it works...

Thanks.